# MTU setting on VLAN on bonded interface

Tags: networking, network-interface, bonding

Current set up is:

```
em2 ---\           / --- bond0.12
        \         /
         \       /
          -bond0-    --- bond0.13
         /       \
        /         \
em2 ---/           \ --- bond0.14
```

When setting up the MTU to 9000 where does it need to be set? Is it in bond0 or the individual interfaces such as bond0.12 etc.?

Answer (score 1):

The MTU must be set on bond0 . 
And on **bond0.XX** you must decrease you MTU by 4 ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.1Q ) .